# Firebase swift 4 : iterate through observe results

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this data

[image]

and i need to retrieve data of node category. 
I tried this code

```
database?.child("restaurants/erbil/Today/category").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
               print(" output            \(String(describing: child.value))")
        }
    })
```

but i will return only data of Burgers node only 
this is the output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your current code loops through the categories, giving you a [DataSnapshot object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot) for each category. You'll want to get the individual key and properties from each child snapshot then, with something like:

```
database?.child("restaurants/erbil/Today/category").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
       print(" key  \(child.key)")
       print(" name \(child.childSnapshot(forPath: "catName").value)")
    }
})
```

Comment: what if i need to retrieve data of node Today?